# Amazon SageMaker ml.p2.xlarge notebook instance speed issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am running AWS Sagemaker and created a notebook instance ml.p2.xlarge machine with elastic inference set as none. I am encountering speed issues during training. The training process is very very slow. I have also restarted the kernel multiple time but it doesn't make any difference. What could be the reason?

Comment: How did you setup your estimator?

Comment: Please clarify.. what you mean by very slow ? Are you comparing this speed againist what? The instance you choose, ml.p2.xlarge is the less powerful one..

Comment: Which kind of models are you training (CNN, RNN, ..etc) ? 
What is the size of your dataset? 
What are your training parameters (e.g what is the batch size used during training)?

Comment: The estimated time for one epoch is approximately 2 hrs that is approximately same when I had trained on my cpu machine previously with no gpu card.

Comment: I am training a CNN based xception net architecture on a 1GB image dataset. Batch size is 16 learning rate 0.0001